# Apex Debug logs not showing Statement executes

Tags: apex, batch, debug-logs

I am trying to run a batch class from anonymous window. In the debug logs i am not getting the statement executes. Only method entry/exit is showing. Debug level for apex is set to finest. It keeps happening like this. Any inputs will be helpful
[image]

Comment: Each single statement of execute method, as well as start and finish is in it's own execution context, and ends up in separate log. Please check those

Comment: I checked all the logs. This log is only covering the logic and the classes that i want to debug. Its not only happening in batch class but in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because batch executes in another transaction. To get result of Batch job use soql to AsyncApexJob

Comment: checked all the logs. This log is only covering the logic and the classes that i want to debug. Its not only happening in batch class but in general.